# Almost surely convergence of a monotone stochastic process

Tags: probability, probability-theory, convergence-divergence, monotone-functions, almost-everywhere

If I have a stochastic process $\{X_t\}$ such that $P(X_t\geq X_{t+1})=1$.

From the monotony of the process can I conclude that

$lim_{t\to +\infty}X_t$ exists almost surely?

Thank you very much

Comment: Define a complement of the union of complements of sets, to see this is true, if you allow $X_{\infty}$ to take values in extended $\mathbb{R}$.

Comment: Actually the process is bounded in the interval [0,1], I forgot to write it. So in this case I think it is not necessary to extend the codomain in $\mathbb R$. It is that correct?

Comment: no, cause there all pointwise sequences are bounded.